# Is it posible to run Ruby(as a language) in a sidecar in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, ruby, kubernetes

I'm working on Python Pod to do one main job. However, for a single step, I need different versions of Ruby, so instead of installing all ruby versions in the "main" python container, I was wondering if I can install a version of ruby per container and then use one of those ruby containers as a sidecar. The idea comes from this use case of the Ruby Docker image

```
docker run -it --rm --name my-running-script -v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp ruby:2.5 ruby your-daemon-or-script.r
```

so I was wondering if we can translate that line to "kubernetes lingo"

Answer (score 1):

You can run any docker image as a second container within a pod. You will see that `pod.spec.containers` is a list which you can run multiple containers (with different docker images/commands/ports/etc).

What you do with that second container is up to you. If you main python app needs to make a call to that container, the ruby container could run a web server. Pods share the same network so your python app could call http://localhost:8080 (or whereever your ruby application exposes a http server).

You can also share a volume between the two containers, so they share the same file system. Read more about that here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/communicate-containers-same-pod-shared-volume/

Hope this helps get you on your way.